# How do you swap cell values for an entire column in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, data-science

[image: Heart disease dataset]

In the "Target" column, 1 means that there is NO heart disease and 0 means that there is heart disease. This is confusing and messes with my regression results. Is there a way to simply change all 0 values to 1 and all 1 values to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['target'] = df['target'].map({0: 1, 1: 0})
```